# iOS: UIStepper : Change the speed at which the value is updated?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uistepper

Is there any way to change the speed at which the value is updated when the user keep his finger pressed on + or - ? I did some research but couldnt find anything ! Any help is appreciated ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First idea - You could assign a UITapRecognizer and a UILongTapGesterRecognizer to the same view.  Have the selector of the tap recognizer increment by one and the long tap recognizer's selector increment by a larger number.

Second idea - you could capture touchesBegan: and start a timer, then start incrementing by a iVar set to 1.  Each time the timer ticks increment the iVar that is used to increment.

Comment: thanks a lot. First idea seems like something I would do. Ill let you know if it works out. I realized the stepper itself starts updating faster after a certain delay. thanks !